# warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `limit')

Tags: unix

I did and try but not able to rectify

```
opal@opal-Inspiron-15-3567:~/PRABHAT/unix$ bash valcode.sh
```

> valcode.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``' valcode.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>
> ```
> IFS="|"
> while echo "Enter deparment code:" ; do
>         read dcode
>         set -- `grep "^$dcode" <<-limit
>         01|accounts|6123
>         02 | admin | 5423
>         03 | marketing |6521
>         04 | personnel |2365
>         05 | production | 9876
>         06 | sales | 1006
>         limit'
>         case $# in
>                 3) echo "deparment name : $2\nEmp-id of head of dept :$3\n"
>                     shift 3 ;;
>                 *) echo "Invalid code" ; continue
>         esac
> done
> ```

the output is not coming as per desire

Answer (score 0):

On line 4 you write **`grep** but the backtick **`** is unmatched. Backticks always come in pairs so the interpreter keeps going looking for the match. Eventually it reached the end of the file without finding it and gives up.

Adding the matching backtick (at the end of the line?) will solve this problem.